# How to create a default constructor with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode, byte-buddy

I use ByteBuddy and I have this code:

```
public class A extends B {
    public A(String a) {
        super(a);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return "HARDCODED VALUE";
    }
}

public abstract class B {
    private final String message;

    protected B(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

My current generation code is:

```
Constructor<T> declaredConstructor;

try {
    declaredConstructor = A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    //fail with exception..
}

new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(A.class, Default.IMITATE_SUPER_CLASS)
    .name(A.class.getCanonicalName() + "$Generated")
    .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)                               
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(declaredConstructor).with("message"))                                                                         
    .make()        
    .load(tClass.getClassLoader(),ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded()
    .newInstance();
```

I want to get instance of class `A`, and also I want to make some actions in constructor after invoke `super()`, like this:

```
public A(){
   super("message");

   // do something special..
}
```

I tried implement with `MethodDelegation.to(DefaultConstructorInterceptor.class)`, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM requires you to hard-code the super method call into a method what is not possible using delegation (also see the javadoc), this is why you cannot use the `MethodDelegation` to invoke the constructor. What you can do is to chain the method call you already have and the delegation by using composition by the `andThen` step as in:

```
MethodCall.invoke(declaredConstructor).with("message")
  .andThen(MethodDelegation.to(DefaultConstructorInterceptor.class));
```